# Change DataSet Designer parameter inference

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, dataset

I'm using the VS2010 DataSet designer to make some select queries with optional parameters similar to this:

```
SELECT CustomerID, FirstName, JoinDate, etc
FROM tblCustomers
WHERE (
    (@CustomerID IS NULL OR CustomerID = @CustomerID) AND
    (@FirstName IS NULL OR FirstName = @FirstName) AND
    (@JoinedBefore IS NULL OR JoinDate < @JoinedBefore) AND
    (@JoinedAfter IS NULL OR JoinDate > @JoinedAfter) AND
    .. etc ..
)
```

The inference for these properties data-types and allow DB null is almost always wrong.  I end up with string types set for date time and vice versa. Over half the fields are always marked as non-null.

That obviously wreaks havoc on my queries.  I can manually change these inference's, but every time I have to update the TableAdapter, it resets them all to what it thinks is best!  Anyone know how to either a) get the inferences right, or b) override them in a permanent way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems VS infers the data type based on the first occurrence of the parameter in the query.  Because I put my @Parater IS NULL OR... first, that confused the designer and caused it to infer wrong a lot of the time.  I swapped the order of my query and now it infers perfectly:

```
SELECT CustomerID, FirstName, JoinDate, etc
FROM tblCustomers
WHERE (
    (CustomerID = @CustomerID OR @CustomerID IS NULL AND
    (FirstName = @FirstName OR @FirstName IS NULL) AND
    (JoinDate < @JoinedBefore OR @JoinedBefore IS NULL) AND
    (JoinDate > @JoinedAfter OR @JoinedAfter IS NULL) AND
    .. etc ..
)
```